# jQuery get value closest input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML code like this:

```html
<tr>
  <td class='qty'><input class='narrow' value='1' /><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>
  <td class='comm'><input class='narrow' value='' size='5'/></td>
</tr>
```

This code will be auto generated by a JS function, so it happens more often.
to get the Value from the first input I use this function:

```js
jQuery('#tbl_order .qty input').bind('change', function() {
```

Within this function I want to get the next input value. I have tried this what does not work

```js
jQuery(this).closest(".comm input").val()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`.closest()`**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by ***testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors*** in the DOM tree.

You can use [**`find()`**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) on the closest *tr* element. I will also prefer using `on()` and `input` event instead of `bind()` and `change` respectively.

**Demo:**

```js
jQuery('#tbl_order .qty input').on('input', function() {
  var nextVal = jQuery(this).closest("tr").find(".comm input").val();
  console.log(nextVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="tbl_order">
    <td class='qty'><input class='narrow' value='1' /><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>
    <td class='comm'><input class='narrow' value='1234' size='5'/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) combines with [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```js
$('#tbl_order .qty input').bind('change', function() {
  var $currentTd = $(this).closest("td");
  var $nextTd = $currentTd.next();
  var value = $nextTd.find("input").val();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl_order">
<tr>
  <td class='qty'><input class='narrow' value='1' /><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>
  <td class='comm'><input class='narrow' value='' size='5'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @beli3ver Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.fa fa-trash').on('click', function () { 
 $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var data = $tr.children('td').map(function () {
      return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    console.log(data);


<table id="tbl_order">
<tr>
<td><input class='narrow' value='1' /><i class='fa fa-trash' aria- 
hidden='true'></i></td>
<td><input class='narrow' value='' size='5'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

this may give you some idea about mapping function. here I give jquery onclick class to fa fa-trash. so whenever the event is fired the particular row get selected. (i hope in the table your getting data from backend code)